# Printing 2 evenly populated lists side by side evenly

Tags: python, string, list, formatting, rows

I'm using the following code to produce 2 lists, nameList and gradeList.

```
nameList[]        
gradeList[]
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
        name = row.select('th strong')
        grade = row.select('td label')
        if grade and name:
            if "/" in grade[0].text:
                gradeList.append(grade[0].text)
                nameShort = re.sub(r'^(.{20}).*$', '\g<1>...', str(name[0].text))
                nameList.append(nameShort)
```

Producing something like:

```
nameList = [“grade 1”,”grade 2222222222”,”grade 3”]
gradeList = [“1/1”,”2/2”,”100000/100000”]
```

I want the program to print the lists in 2 clean columns, side by side. Within each column, I want the data to align to the left. The lists (without fail) will always be evenly populated. The first column (nameList) will never be longer than 25 characters. What I am looking for would be similar to the following:

```
        Assignment          Grade
0       grade 1             1/1
1       grade 2222222222    2/2
2       grade 3             100000/100000
```

I've tried to use pandas and it worked, but the formatting was weird and out of place. It wouldn't align to the left like I want. I believe this happened because the data each has a different character length in both lists (shown above).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
nameList = ["grade 1", "grade 2222222222", "grade 3"]
gradeList = ["1/1", "2/2", "100000/100000"]

fmt = '{:<8}{:<20}{}'

print(fmt.format('', 'Assignment', 'Grade'))
for i, (name, grade) in enumerate(zip(nameList, gradeList)):
    print(fmt.format(i, name, grade))
```

output:

```
        Assignment          Grade
0       grade 1             1/1
1       grade 2222222222    2/2
2       grade 3             100000/100000
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`printf` style formatting using % operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

```
fmt = '%-8s%-20s%s'

print(fmt % ('', 'Assignment', 'Grade'))
for i, (name, grade) in enumerate(zip(nameList, gradeList)):
    print(fmt % (i, name, grade))
```

Comment: What is "fmt = '{:<8}{:<20}{}'" defining? When I run this code, the program prints out the list like 20 times.

Comment: @JacksonBlankenship, It's a format string to instruct `str.format` how to format arguments: `{:<8}` is shrotcut for `{0:<8}`. `0` mean 0th (first argument), `:` is to begin format specification, `<`: left alignment, `8` means width.

Comment: @JacksonBlankenship, If you want to know more about Format string syntax, following the link in the answer or this: [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Comment: @JacksonBlankenship, For `printf`-style formatting, follow this link: [`printf`-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)

Comment: Oh it got caught up in another for loop! My bad, works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Given two lists

```
nameList = ['grade 1','grade 2222222222','grade 3']
gradeList = ['1/1','2/2','100000/100000']
```

tab separated format.  using zip() two iterate through both lists at the same time

```
print 'Assignment \t\tGrade' 
for n,g in zip(nameList,gradeList):
    print n + '\t\t\t' + g


Assignment         Grade
grade 1            1/1
grade 2222222222   2/2
grade 3            100000/100000
```

Comment: does not work if every element in the left column does not end in the same tab column

Answer (score 0):

You can use F-Strings, I think it becomes more clear:

```
nameList = ["grade 1", "grade 2222222222", "grade 3"]
gradeList = ["1/1", "2/2", "100000/100000"]

# Table header
print(f'{"":<8} {"Assignment":<20} {"Grade":<20}')

# Table content
for i, (name, grade) in enumerate(zip(nameList, gradeList)):
    print(f'{i:<8} {name:<20} {grade:<20}')
```

Result:

```
         Assignment           Grade               
0        grade 1              1/1                 
1        grade 2222222222     2/2                 
2        grade 3              100000/100000
```