# Python printing lists side by side

Tags: python, dictionary, multiple-columns

everyone.  I am new to Python and in dire need of some help.  I am trying to count the unique values in a few lists and then print the output side by side as columns. I can count them fine using collections. However, I don't know how to print them side by side. Is there any pythonic way to concatenate or display them as columns side by side?

I tried the below but to no avail. ANY help is well appreciated.

```
print(str(parsed_list(a)) + str(parsed_list(b)) + str(parsed_list(b)))
NoneNoneNone
```

My Sample Testable Code (Python3):

```
import collections, operator

a = ['Black Cat', 'Black Dog', 'Black Mouse']
b = ['Bird', 'Bird', 'Parrot']
c = ['Eagle', 'Eagle', 'Eagle', 'Hawk']


def parsed_list(list):
    y = collections.Counter(list)
    for k, v in sorted(y.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
        z = (str(k).ljust(12, ' ') + (str(v)))
        print(z)

print('Column1          Column2             Column3')
print('-' * 45)
parsed_list(a)
parsed_list(b)
parsed_list(c)
```

Current:

```
Column1          Column2             Column3
---------------------------------------------
Black Cat   1
Black Dog   1
Black Mouse 1
Bird        2
Parrot      1
Eagle       3
Hawk        1
```

Desired Output:

```
Column1          Column2      Column3
----------------------------------------
Black Cat   1    Bird     2   Eagle  3
Black Dog   1    Parrot   1   Hawk   1
Black Mouse 1
```

Comment: Have you looked at using Pandas to deal with tabular data like that?

Comment: @cricket_007 Unfortunately this script is being performed on a system in which I cannot (not allowed) install Pandas. Is there not a native way to do this? Seems like something that would be frequently needed.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a dependency on the [tabulate module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate):

```
import collections
from itertools import zip_longest
import operator

from tabulate import tabulate

def parsed_list(lst):
    width = max(len(item) for item in lst)
    return ['{key} {value}'.format(key=key.ljust(width), value=value)
            for key, value in sorted(
                collections.Counter(lst).items(),
                key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)]

a = parsed_list(['Black Cat', 'Black Dog', 'Black Mouse'])
b = parsed_list(['Bird', 'Bird', 'Parrot'])
c = parsed_list(['Eagle', 'Eagle', 'Eagle', 'Hawk'])

print(tabulate(zip_longest(a, b, c), headers=["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"]))

# Output:
# Column 1       Column 2       Column 3
# -------------  -------------  -------------
# Black Mouse 1  Bird        2  Eagle       3
# Black Dog   1  Parrot      1  Hawk        1
# Black Cat   1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import zip_longest
a = ['Black Cat', 'Black Dog', 'Black Mouse']
b = ['Bird', 'Bird', 'Parrot']
c = ['Eagle', 'Eagle', 'Eagle', 'Hawk']

def parse(lst):
    c = Counter(lst)
    r = []
    for s, cnt in c.most_common():
        r += ['%12s%3i' % (s, cnt)]
    return r 

for cols in zip_longest(parse(a), parse(b), parse(c), fillvalue=15*' '):
    print(' '.join(cols))
```

This produces:

```
   Black Cat  1         Bird  2        Eagle  3
 Black Mouse  1       Parrot  1         Hawk  1
   Black Dog  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you can manually build your own library, but Python seems to have a format method built into the string type that could work well for your purpose.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663924/printing-2-evenly-populated-lists-side-by-side-evenly) of a previous post can help you out! Give it a shot!