# Accessing Anaconda Channels from Mamba

Tags: python, windows, conda, miniconda, mamba

I am building my Python environment around `micromamba`.
I was wondering how can I use the Anaconda channels to download packages as described in conda channels: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/channels.html.

By default `micromamba` is configured to work with `conda-forge` yet I'd like to access the numpy and scipy packages of Anaconda (Which are compiled using MKL).

#### Motivation

I am asking since when I install from `conda-forge` by looking at the configuration of numpy I get:

```
python -c "import numpy as np; np.show_config()"
blas_info:
    libraries = ['cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Applications/Python\\Library\\lib']
    include_dirs = ['C:/Applications/Python\\Library\\include']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    libraries = ['cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Applications/Python\\Library\\lib']
    include_dirs = ['C:/Applications/Python\\Library\\include']
    language = f77
lapack_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas', 'lapack', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Applications/Python\\Library\\lib']
    language = f77
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas', 'lapack', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Applications/Python\\Library\\lib']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Applications/Python\\Library\\include']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2,AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX
    not found = AVX512_CNL
```

Which doesn't seem to be linked to MKL.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the Anaconda builds to use MKL. Conda Forge uses a different strategy for integrating BLAS/LAPACK implementations, which can mask the info shown from  `np.show_config()` ([some details here](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#switching-blas-implementation)). Adding the specification

```yaml
'blas=*=*mkl'
```

to your package specifications (either in YAML or in `conda install`) will ensure Conda Forge NumPy, etc. will use MKL.

Otherwise, one can switch to using Anaconda packages by adding the `anaconda` channel, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68991641/570918)<sup>**1**</sup>. Just be aware that [channel mixing can be messy](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels). Personally, I would just stick to Conda Forge.

---

<sub>**[1]:** While I previously recommended using `anaconda` channel in the other answer, I have since read up more the Conda Forge strategy.</sub>

Comment: What's the default if one didn't do anything? What to write in the `yaml` file to define the environment?

Comment: good day dear Merv - thanks this is very heplful. Well i am new to Python and i want to install a environment - ihave read this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421163/anaconda-vs-miniconda

well should i take mamba instead - plz advice

Comment: @Thomas there is no explicit default, which means that the solver will try to take whatever has been updated most recently. Most often I see`openblas` installed on **osx-64** platform when I don't specify. There is [documentation on how to define a YAML](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually).  The `blas=*=*mkl` specification would go under the `dependencies` section.

Comment: @thannen Mamba is an add-on - it can be added to any **base** installation. That other thread is a better place to discuss installers. Personally, I recommend MambaForge to professional practitioners (e.g., bioinformaticians).